# Any sandboxing software that prevents scattered application files?

Tags: windows, software-development, security, sandbox

I'm looking for software that can sandbox applications, but without some of the traditional limitations. This is my use-case:

I want to run Node and have it executable so Visual Studio Code can access the executable for extensions and such, but I do not want my `%appdata%` directory or system registry cluttered by all of NPM's garbage.

I also want Visual Studio and Visual Studio Build Tools, but as some may know, uninstalling that is an absolute ***pain*** in the ass.

Let me use Docker images as an analogy. It keeps the entire application inside of a container, where it is non persistent except for explicit exclusions. It does not modify the host system in *any way*. It also allows ports to be exposed, so that any network services can be accessed as if they were on the host.

Some applications, if allowed, should be able to access the host's environment variables (such as `%path%`) so that binaries such as `python.exe` can be accessed directly.

I'm looking for Docker, but for applications on Windows, and the "ports" are executables that other applications can use. When I delete the sandbox that an application is running in, it should appear as if the application was **never run** on the host system.

I've taken a look at [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) and some alternatives, but they don't really fit the requirements that I've listed above.

Open Source or free are two massive selling points, but it doesn't have to be.

Thank you for your time.